# Missing const_iterator overload of std::vector::erase() with g++ 4.8

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, g++

The [following example](http://ideone.com/98uLBy) will not compile using g++ 4.8.2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> v {1, 2, 3};

    v.erase(v.cbegin()); // Compiler complains

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler says the following.  (It isn't very readable, but it's complaining that there's not a known conversion between `vector<int>::const_iterator` and `vector<int>::iterator`.)

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:8:20: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<int>::erase(std::vector<int>::const_iterator)’
  v.erase(v.cbegin());
                    ^
prog.cpp:8:20: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/vector:69:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/vector.tcc:134:5: note: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::erase(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator) [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = int*]
     vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/vector.tcc:134:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::vector<int>::const_iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> >}’ to ‘std::vector<int>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >}’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/vector.tcc:146:5: note: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::erase(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator) [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = int*]
     vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/vector.tcc:146:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

**Why?**  The C++11 standard plainly states, in §23.3.6.5, that the `vector::erase` function **takes a `const_iterator`**.  (Paraphrases are [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/).)

What's a good workaround, assuming that I must use a `const_iterator`?

Comment: It's simply not yet implemented.

Comment: That's irritating... question edited; what's a good workaround?

Comment: The workaround would be to use non-const iterators.

Comment: use `begin` instead of `cbegin`?

Comment: @WeaselFox that is not possible for const map objects (at least not without casting)

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that if the OP is calling `vector::erase` then it's a non-const object.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a known bug in gcc: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57158

erase requires an iterator instead of a const_iterator with current gcc's.

Comment: Hmmm.  That bug is marked a duplicate of a resolved bug, but for `deque`.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty "Target Milestone:  4.9.0" Resolved doesn't mean "fixed in every version".

Comment: @stefan Oh, gotcha, I missed that.  Well drat.  Any tips on converting between the two, or should I just suck it up and use a non-`const` iterator?

Comment: @thirtythreeforty Seeing as you need a hack around a specific compiler & library version, you could look at their data layout and see if you could just `reinterpret_cast` through pointers (or use a `union { const_iterator ci; iterator i; }`).

Comment: Just a note, I *can* use a `reinterpret_cast` (I tried it and **it works**), but **this is definitely a hack and not to be used if reliability/portability is required.**

Comment: The `reinterpret_cast` is undefined behaviour, doing so violates the type-based alias analysis and could lead to strange results.

Comment: Technically that's the `list` version of the bug, the vector version is [55675](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55675)

Answer (score 8):

You can get a non-const iterator via pointer arithmetic, here's a helper function to do that:

```
template<typename T>
  typename std::vector<T>::iterator
  const_iterator_cast(std::vector<T>& v, typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator iter)
  {
    return v.begin() + (iter - v.cbegin());
  }
```

used like so:

```
std::vector<T> v(1);
auto citer = v.cbegin();
v.erase( const_iterator_cast(v, citer) );
```

Comment: @rabensky: Try ```return std::next(v.begin(), std::distance(v.cbegin(), iter));```.

Comment: @rabensky which is fine because the question is specifically about `std::vector` and that has random access iterators. And the helper function clearly takes an argument of type `std::vector<T>&`, so it only works with `std::vector`.