# C++: SFINAE to differentiate fill and range constructors?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45847787/8385554) is a question asking about how to differentiate fill and range constructors. The code is copied here:

```
template <typename T>
struct NaiveVector {
    vector<T> v;
    NaiveVector(size_t num, const T &val) : v(num, val) { // fill
        cout << "(int num, const T &val)" << endl;
    }

    template <typename InputIterator>
    NaiveVector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) : v(first, last) { // range
        cout << "(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)" << endl;
    }
};
```

The code above doesn't work, as described in that question. The solution is using SFINAE to define the range constructor, like this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45847950/8385554):

```
template
<
    typename InputIterator
,   typename = typename ::std::enable_if
    <
        ::std::is_same
        <
            T &
        ,   typename ::std::remove_const
            <
                decltype(*(::std::declval< InputIterator >()))
            >::type
        >::value
    ,  void
    >::type
>
NaiveVector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) : v(first, last)
{
    cout << "(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)" << endl;
}
```

This gist of this solution is comparing the dereferenced type of `InputIterator` with `T &`. If it is truly an iterator that points to `T`, the comparison of `std::is_same` will be true, and the range constructor will be selected; if it is not an iterator, there will be a template substitution failure so the range constructor will be deleted, and hence the fill constructor will be selected.

However, there is a problem for the solution above. If the input `InputIterator` is of `const_iterator` type (e.g. `cbegin()`), then dereferencing it will yield a `const T &`, and its `const`-ness cannot be removed by `std::remove_const` (explained [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv)), so the comparison in `std::is_same` will be false, resulting in the range constructor being wrongly deleted.

> <s>GNU's C++ STL had a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19559235) possibly (**I guess**) because of this. In this bug, the method only accepts an iterator, but not a const_iterator.</s>

**Questions**:

(1) is there a **nicer** workaround than combining two `std::is_same` conditions with an OR operator, one comparing the dereferenced type with `T &`, the other with `const T &`?

(2) if the workaround described in (1) is adopted, is `std::remove_const` still necessary, now that it cannot remove `const`-ness from a reference type, and dereferencing an (const or non-const) iterator will always yield a reference, either `const T &` or `T &`.

Comment: `std::is_constructible<T, decltype(*::std::declval< InputIterator >())>` seems even better (it handles possible bool wrapper of `std::vector<bool>`).

Comment: @Jarod42 ..and it can handle the problem said in this question? Sorry i am not near a computer now.

Comment: The bug for `std::vector:erase` is unrelated to SFINAE.

Comment: @Jarod42 ok I stroke through that paragraph:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The example code is indeed wrong, as it doesn't support `const_iterator`, `std::decay` would be more appropriate:

```
template
<
    typename InputIterator
,   typename = typename ::std::enable_if
    <
        ::std::is_same
        <
            T
        ,   typename ::std::decay
            <
                decltype(*(::std::declval< InputIterator >()))
            >::type
        >::value
    ,  void
    >::type
>
NaiveVector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

or even simpler `std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type`.

But even better, IMO would be `std::is_constructible`. That handle when iterator returns wrapper (as potentially `std::vector<bool>`)

```
template <typename InputIterator,
          typename ::std::enable_if<
              ::std::is_constructible<
                  T,
                  decltype(*::std::declval<InputIterator>())
              >::value
          >::type* = nullptr
>
NaiveVector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/hvHnXR)

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is correct. 
To complete it, I put here the code using `iterator_traits`. 
I think it is conceptually much better:

```
template<
    typename InputIterator, 
    typename = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type
>
NaiveVector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

---

For reference, this is how it is done in gcc C++11 library (it checks the InputIter concept, which can be more restrictive):

```
  template<typename _InputIterator,
           typename = std::_RequireInputIter<_InputIterator>>
    vector(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
           const allocator_type& __a = allocator_type())
    : _Base(__a)
    { _M_initialize_dispatch(__first, __last, __false_type()); }
```

In old C++98, <s>surprisingly nothing special is done, so probably there are ambiguous cases for `std::vector<std::size_t>` (I guess!)</s> the dispatch is done inside the constructor function, in case `InputIterator` is not really an InputIterator.

```
  template<typename _InputIterator>
    vector(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
           const allocator_type& __a = allocator_type())
    : _Base(__a)
    {
      // Check whether it's an integral type.  If so, it's not an iterator.
      typedef typename std::__is_integer<_InputIterator>::__type _Integral;
      _M_initialize_dispatch(__first, __last, _Integral());
    }
```

Comment: Nothing special? What do you think that _M_initialize_dispatch call with _Integral() does?

Comment: Ah, ok `initialize_dispatch` will compile-check for non-iterator cases. It might, I didn't check. (Even if it does the naming is confusing because the InputIterator will not be an InputIterator.) So, now I am surprised by the naming. :)